# Referencing a file in the user home directory with file://

Tags: macos, mac

Is there any way to reference a file in the local user directory, using file://, without specifying the user name?

I thought file://~/Desktop/File.doc might work, but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 1):

**No, it's not possible to do that.** The `~` shortcut is for user convenience only, and would be ambiguous when used as part of an URL, especially if that URL was embedded in a document – whose home directory would be used, then? The file owner's? The reader's? It would change depending on the environment.

Also note that your example URL, `file://~/Desktop/File.doc`, actually means the file `/Desktop/File.doc` in a computer named "`~`". The syntax for `file:` URLs is `file://<host>/<path>`, and the third slash must not be omitted even when the hostname is empty (referring to a local path).

Comment: The reason for wanting to do this is we have many users who have dropbox installed and we want to be able to exchange links to files by email.  It is installed in the same location on each PC and each user has the same shared folders.  So we want the URL to be ambiguous.  The dropbox share a link feature is unfortunately no use.

Comment: And so what is wanted is file:///~/Desktop/File.doc, or some equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this reference from Apple for more information:

[Specifying the Path to a File or Directory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html)

Comment: And just what exactly in there is useful here?